# Can you create files on Firebase after deployment?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using the node modules: cross-spawn, execa, and spawn-cmd, to run an application. It works when I run the application on localhost but when I deploy it to Firebase and run it from there, I can't find the file output. The path should be fine because it works on localhost and doesn't give me errors once deployed.

I realised the application may be running and outputting the file but it's not saving to my local directory. Does Firebase allow you to create files in the deployed Functions folder? If so, how can I access it?

This is how I'm running it:

```
const spawn = require('cross-spawn').spawn;

spawn('cb.exe', args.split(" "), { stdio: 'inherit', cwd: 'files/cb/'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write new files in your deployed functions folder.  The permissions on the folder and files allows read-only access.

The only folder you may write to is /tmp, and you can read about it in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#local_disk):

> Cloud Functions provides access to a local disk mount point (/tmp)
>   which is known as a "tmpfs" volume in which data written to the volume
>   is stored in memory. There is no specific fee associated with this
>   however writing data to the /tmp mountpoint will consume memory
>   resources provisioned for the function.

You should use [os.tmpdir](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_tmpdir) to get a hold of this path rather than hard coding it.

It is also impossible to write files into your deployed Firebase Hosting files, which is a completely different product.